# PHP: Why when you are adding value to array with not existing index it doesnt raise NOTICE?

Tags: php, arrays

For example:

```
$array = [];

echo $array['bar']; // PHP NOTICE - trying to access not existing key`

$array['bar'][] = 'foo'; // Nothing
```

I understand that it creates array with that index 'bar', but how does PHP deals with that internally?

Comment: That's just how it works.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's how a religion starts, don't question just follow. OPs question is legitimate. Your answer is not.

Comment: @Andrew:  That's funny, I didn't post an answer.

Comment: Comment, whatever. Point stands.

Comment: This article will explain more about how PHP is internally handling arrays: https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html

Comment: @Dragos thanks!! it actually might be what i'm looking for ! :)

Answer (score 4):

`$array['bar'][] = 'foo';` doesn't return a notice or error because there is no error. You are creating a new array index, and another index within that, and assigning a value to it. That's what the statement means. There's no error to return.

If you want to have behaviour for if a particular array index is not set, you can use array_key_exists (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if(array_key_exists('bar', $array)){
    $array['bar'][] = 'foo';
} else {
    // something else
}
```

That's if this question is functional (ie., you're trying to accomplish something specific). If the question is more conceptual - why doesn't PHP read the variable assignment as an error:

PHP is capable of initializing and assigning a variable in one line, ie `$foo = 'bar'`. This does not return an error even though `$foo` was not previously defined because PHP initializes the variable first. The same method holds true for array indexes. `$array['foo'][] = 'bar'` doesn't return an error or a notice because PHP is initializing the array index just as it would a variable.

Comment: You still didn't answered the question, namely why (and how does PHP internally handle that) it DOES throw a notice when you're trying to access an inexisting key, but  it does not throw any notice when you're trying to set a value for an inexisting key of an array

Comment: Because functionally speaking, you AREN'T trying to set a value for a nonexistent key. You're setting a key, and another key inside it, and assigning a value to THAT key. PHP is intelligent enough to cascade that key creation down. That's opposed to when you try to ACCESS a key that doesn't exist, in which case there's nothing PHP can do.

Comment: @Dragos The proceducre of creating a previously non-existing variable is called initialization. In PHP you can also initialize a variable by assigning a value to previously non-existing variable. There wouldn't be any notice in this case either. It is the same when you set a value for new key in an array.

Comment: @PeregrineStudios  thanks for answer and yes, my question  is more conceptual. I can understand how PHP deals with that in abstract sense, but the part 'PHP is able to correct'  is a bit mistery for me:)

Comment: Clarified my answer a little including Dragos' comment. I hope it clears things up a bit.

Comment: I'm still waiting that moment when people actually read and understand the question before posting an answer.
This is not a question about PHP syntax and how one solves a problem in PHP, but it's rather a question of C.